# Unable to remotely connect to Postgresql 9.5 instance

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, connectivity, postgresql-9.5, remote

I am struggling to connect to a remote Postgresql 9.5 instance running on Ubuntu 16.10.
The usual:

> psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
>     Is the server
>   running on host "xx.xx.xx.xx" and accepting   TCP/IP connections on
>   port 5432?

My postgresql.conf includes

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

confirmed by output from

```
netstat -nlp | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22981/postgres      
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      22981/postgres      
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3320886  22981/postgres       /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Apart from my specific IP address & range, I have also tried the following entries in pg_hba.conf:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5                                                                                                                                                                                       
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
host    all             all             all                     md5
host    all             all             *                       md5
```

I have the following ufw rules:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
5432                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

However, the problem persists even when disabling the firewall.

Scanning with nmap:

```
nmap xx.xx.xx.xx -p5432

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-02-13 09:17 SAST
Nmap scan report for xx.xx.xx.xx
Host is up (0.0074s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5432/tcp filtered postgresql
```

Almost all similar questions on SE seem to be solved with

> listen_addresses='*'

which is not an issue here.

Really confused by this, help would be greatly appreciated.

The machine is not down as I am able to ssh into the machine. Additionally nginx server is also accessible. Telnet to port 5432 times out.

There is no local router in front of the ubuntu server, it is a dedicated server with public network interface that is bound to the xx.xx.xx.xx address. This is a migration from a previous generation box at the same hosting company who does not offer the option of an additional firewall device.  This is a clean Ubuntu 16.10 server install.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out my hosting provider moved the server behind a managed firewall without notice.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is already a long ago answered question, for informational purposes to others facing the same issue, in this case the result of `nmap` does give you the answer as well.

PORT STATE SERVICE --> *5432/tcp **filtered** postgresql*

If you look at the documentation on nmap, it mentions that

> **Filtered** means that a firewall, filter, or other **network obstacle** is blocking the port so that Nmap cannot tell whether it is open or closed.

So the issue is in the network rather than the PostgreSQL configuration.